# Linearization using Taylor series

Tags: taylor-expansion, linearization

I'm trying to understand this approximation:

$x \sqrt{\bigg(1+\alpha\Big(\frac{y}{x}-1\Big)\bigg)\bigg/\bigg(1+\alpha\Big(\frac{x}{y}-1\Big)\bigg)} \approx x\bigg(1+\frac{\alpha}{2}\Big(\frac{y}{x}-1-\frac{x}{y}+1\Big)\bigg)$

and this one:

$\Large\frac{(x^3 (1-\alpha)+y^3\alpha)\Big(\frac{(1-\alpha)}{x}+\frac{\alpha}{y}\Big)}{(x(1-\alpha)+y\alpha)^2}\approx 1+\alpha\frac{x}{y}\bigg(\frac{y^2}{x^2}-1\bigg)^2$

According to the brief explanation, we derive the approximation using Taylor series linearization.

I'm familiar with Taylor expansion of $f(x\pm ah)$, but not with linearization/approximation using Taylor.

I suspect there's some derivation involved, but I'm not too sure.

Can someone help?

[image]

Comment: If $f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x - a) + f''(a)/2! (x-a)^2 \dots $ is the Taylor series of $f(x)$, then the linearization is just the first two terms: $L(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$.  Note that this is really just the tangent line to $f(x)$ at $x = a$.

Comment: I'm still confused, we have three variables, $x$ $y$ and $\alpha$. How should I derivate the equation? With respect to $x$, $y$ or $\alpha$?

Comment: I believe $\alpha$ is the variable that is infinitesimal. $x$ and $y$ can just be seen as some coefficients.